# autostart applications on diferent workspaces

Tags: workspace

I wanted to raise another question since I am configuring my new laptop at the moment.
So I am using a lot of VMs and also do a lot of managing on ESXis. Therefore I have installed VMware workstation to load the VMs. 
I played around with different workspaces which is really working great. 
What I want to have right now if a custom "application/starter" to run a specific VM in fullscreen but I want to have it started on a second workspace.

I already checked the VMware Workstation options and I am able to start the VM with the vmwarerun command and from my understanding I should be able to use devilspie or other tools to start on the 2nd workspace in fullscreen.

So my overall achievement will be to have the mail workspace in the middle. on the left/first workspace run spotify and mailspring and on the right workspace which will be the third one I want to run a Win10 VM where I have several windows applications running. and this should be running on startup

in addition to that a kind of a starter in plank will be great but nice to have :)

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: I agree this would be an excellent feature. Have you searched the Elementary issues for one that matches your needs?

[This one](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/571) looks relevant.

Comment: Blockbuster seems not to be available anymore but I think with a startup script I should be able to accomplish this.
I will let you know about my findings

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this topic. What I have achieved so far:
switched from VMware to Virtualbox since this is running much smoother
created a shortcut of each VM on the "desktop" and modified the file in order to have a custom icon set and but this in the plank panel. So I have 3 icons reflecting kali linux, windows and a testing eOS.

Comment: I did some testing with devilspie2 and I am able to shift the VirtualBox windows on the 2nd, 3rd workspace and set it to fullscreen. 
with devilspie2 I am still in the testing phase and I have to create a script with a listener when the application will be opened.  hope I will fix this soon. 
besides of this I am pretty happy with this solution for now